# How to tell your employers that you want to quit (very) early for a better opportunity?

Tags: resignation, asia

I love doing research. I applied to some universities for MRes (because I only have 3-yr bachelor's degree) and could not get any scholarship.

Since I couldn't afford a MRes program, I decided to apply for a job and wanted to work there for ~ 2 years before applying to graduate schools.

I got an industry job offer (junior position) at a prestigious firm about 1 month ago. I enjoy working for this company. Everyone there is friendly and supportive. They like me a lot.

However, recently, my former supervisor, who works in another country, has offered me an opportunity to do (funded) research as he has just won a huge grant from the government. The research topic is very interesting. The pay-rate is much higher than the current job; more importantly, I can finally do research without any financial burdens.

Of course, I will accept his offer.  I am not a job hopper; however, I will need to terminate my employment contract, and that will probably hurt my reputation.

I want to ask if this looks "very bad" in the eyes of employers, and what should I tell my employer to make them understand my situation?

Comment: Tell the employer what you told us. Don't expect them to be happy about it; they've wasted time and money bringing you in. A good management team will understand that there are opportunities you feel you can't pass up, but they are entitled to be grumpy about it.

Comment: Make sure the job offer is real and the contract is signed. Then, rip the bandage off. There is nothing you can say that will salvage this relationship. And you will need to remove this one-month job from your resume and your LinkedIn entirely. A one month hole is ten times better than a one month job that you backtracked on. Also, you may not want to tell your current employer exactly where you're leaving because they could try to sabotage that offer.

Comment: Do you have a probation period?  They are made for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need to check is any employment documents you signed related to the first company. These could have been signed related to the offer, or the pre-employment phase, and the  first days of work. You want to understand if there are any potential penalties and notice periods.

> my former supervisor, who works in another country, has offered me an
> opportunity to do (funded) research as he has just won a huge grant
> from the government.

Before talking to your current employer make sure all the visa and related documents connected to the new country are resolved. These things can take time, you don't want to tell the current company too early, and have to ask for an extension or have a few months with no income.

> I want to ask if this looks "very bad" in the eyes of employers, and
> what should I tell my employer to make them understand my situation?

The range of reactions to this announcement will range from anger, to neutral, to being happy for you. You don't have to provide many details.  In fact the fewer the better. Any excuse you give them may change some minds, but none of them will change the financial impact, or the hole in the workforce.

Going forward it isn't necessary to list a one month job on the resume or LinkedIn profile. But do keep records of your employment with them because you may be required to provide details for a background check, or other form that requires documenting for the last x years.

Answer (score 2):

To Paraphrase a classic Movie:

"I was made an offer I can't refuse"

Now, from your current employers perspective this can be annoying. Afterall, after 1 month they've probably only just finished training you.

But at the same time, they will likely understand if it's as good an opportunity as you've told us.

The only thing I'd lead with is not to say that you left because of the increased pay - I'd start with talking about how passionate you are about the research topic, then say that it comes with a higher pay rate.

Answer (score 0):

As a current employer I can tell you that only 10% of what you say will matter on his/her reaction and what he will think of you. It will all depend on the personality of your employer and what he has sacrificed (money, time, reputation, etc...) to hire and keep you.

You can consider it as if the script is already written even before you break the news to him, nothing you say or do will change the plot of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will look bad on your resume.  As an employer, it is one of the things I look for.  How often have they changed jobs, will they stay with me for a length of time?  This is because, there is a significant investment, first in advertising, then interviewing, signing contracts and orienteering.

If there is only one such incident in your CV, it will not matter much.  If there a series of such job hopping incidents, then I wouldn't be hiring you.

Having said that, every one is fickle.  The employer is NOT loyal to you, when it suits them, they will let you go (unless you have managed to make good personal relations with management).  You have to look out for yourself.

As an employee, in the past, I would always give my current employer the maximum amount of notice and I would offer to

- Either complete the current project, if it has less than a month to run (often in my spare time)
- Or offer to train my replacement, to take some of the burden off them.

When I told one of my employers, he was really gutted.  For him, I actually searched for and found my replacement, one that was as good (even better in some areas) as me.